# How to cast `Int8?` to `Int?`?

Tags: ios, swift, casting, option-type

I have a `UInt8?` variable named `seconds` that I need to pass to a function accepting `Int?`.

This leads to *Cannot convert value of type `UInt8?` to expected argument type `Int?`*.

This means I have to cast, and so I tried the obvious:

```
Int?(seconds)
```

But this results in: *`UInt8?` is not convertible to `Int`*.

Of course I could do:

```
(seconds == nil) ? nil : Int(seconds!)
```

But WTF, does it really have to be so contrived?

Comment: "does it really have to be so contrived?" Nope :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your type is `Optional<UInt8>`. A `UInt8` can always be converted to an `Int` with the function `Int.init`. But since it's wrapped in an `Optional`, you'll have to map that function over the optional, yielding a new value of type `Optional<Int>`:

```
seconds.map(Int.init)
```

[`Optional.map(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1539476-map) and its companion [`flatMap`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1540500-flatmap) often make working with optionals a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks! What exactly do you mean with "map that function over the optional"? Could you please elaborate a bit more? Also, what other things can you do with `Optional.map(_:)`; do you know a good tutorial perhaps?

Comment: `Optional` is a functor. That's a term from functional programming. A functor is a type that can be mapped over. I'm sure you're familiar with mapping a function over an array. Arrays are functors as well. `Optional` is similar in the sense that is a container, i.e. it either contains a value or it doesn't. When it does, the function (or closure) you pass to it, will be applied to the contained value. [This](https://www.mokacoding.com/blog/functor-applicative-monads-in-pictures/) might help